# Git Hide Local Branch History

Tags: git, branch

- Before a push I want to merge with master but I do not want my branch's commit messages appear in the remote repository.
- In graph: A: Master B - D : MyLocal Branch commits and comments.

  ```
  A             E
   \          /
     B - C - D
  ```
- I want only E's comment to appear in case of a push (merge operation)

Comment: You want to "squash" a series of commits.  There are several answers here on StackOverflow that describe how to do that, as well as documentation that will crop up if you search for that term using your favorite search engine.

Comment: Read about `squash`. Also, refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git). Also, recently Github added this [feature](https://github.com/blog/2141-squash-your-commits)